# Is there a way to make a div on my website that follows on top when scrolling down?

Tags: javascript, css, xhtml, prototypejs

I'm trying to replicate this: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#typography (the one on top that has the tabs: | Typography | Code Tables | Forms | Buttons | Icons by Glyphicons |). I'd like to replicate that same fast acting effect.

I'd like to make this div do the same:

```
#panel {
    margin: auto;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    border-top: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1),
    1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1),
    -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1),
    0 -1px rgb(255,255,255) inset,
    0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2) inset,
    1px 0 rgb(255,255,255) inset,
    -1px 0 rgb(255,255,255) inset;
    background: #E8E8E8;    
    width: 75%;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
    text-shadow: 0 1px white;
    padding: 2px 0px 2px 8px;
    margin-top: -149px;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 11px;
}
```

on my website: http://www.bobbaxtrade.com

Thanks :)

Comment: I've already tried to copy the code and change it to my div, but nothing happens.. Also I'm using prototypejs as main library. I Know that changing the $'s for jQuery makes it work, but in my case it's not.

Answer (score 2):

I've created the jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/cBk7q/

So, you need to add a class to your css rules, to make your div static on top of the window:

```
.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Then, add a jQuery function to bind the scroll event and add the fixed class when you reach the desired position:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $mydiv = $("#mydiv"),
        origTop = $("#mydiv").position().top;

    $(window).scroll(function(e) {
        if( document.body.scrollTop > origTop) {
            console.log($mydiv.hasClass('fixed'));
            $mydiv.addClass("fixed");
        }
        else {
            console.log('c ' + (document.body.scrollTop > origTop));
            $mydiv.removeClass("fixed");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I'm going to try changing "#mydiv" with #panel. I hope it works :) Also I'm using a different library do you know how to make the code so that it won't interfere? I think it's something like "jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function($)" but i don't know where to place it.

Comment: sorry bro. can't help you unless you tell me which library you are using. and jQuery can be used in no-conflict mode

Comment: prototypejs is the library used by my forum script, I'm going to try changing every $ for jquery.

Comment: that should work. and by the way, do check out how to use jquery in no conflict mode, if you don't already know it.

Comment: If still not working, try adding `jQuery.noConflict();` before any other custom scripting, even if you don't use the `$` for jQuery. The noConflict() method will override other previously declared `$` functions to not affect prototype.

Comment: Where on the code do I use the no-conflict. I'm sorry i'm pretty new. It's not working replacing every $ with jQuery :(

Comment: and yes, one more thing, if you don't want any changes, you can try this:
(function($) {
   // the same code works perfectly fine here, except $ means jquery now.
})(jQuery)

and place this in document load or something you feel is ok

Comment: I tried it like but not working `code`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
var $mydiv = $("#panel"),
    origTop = $("#panel").position().top;

$(window).scroll(function(e) {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > origTop) {
        console.log($mydiv.hasClass('fixed'));
        $mydiv.addClass("fixed");
    }
    else {
        console.log('c ' + (document.body.scrollTop > origTop));
        $mydiv.removeClass("fixed");
    }
});​
</script>

Comment: You have the noConflict, but still need to use jQuery instead of $, or you can create a new var like `$j = jQuery.noConflict();` and replace all existing $ for $j

Comment: panel still won't scroll down :( wow I can't imagine what could be wrong. I'm placing the code in the right place and everthing.

Comment: hey, i've updated the fiddle, check it out. Now, I am using prototype as the framework (as are you) and am adding jquery using script tag.

Answer (score 1):

The Bootstrap website explains you [how to use this feature](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navbar).

If you are using bootstrap, you can use the CSS class `navbar-fixed-top` to get this behavior:

```html
<div id="panel" class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  ...
</div>
```

If you want the effect, that the navigation bar only becomes fixed after scrolling over it, you need to add the class `navbar-fixed-top` dynamically with some JavaScript (taken from [LessCSS](http://lesscss.org)).

Suppose you have some HTML

```html
<!-- some content -->
<div id ="panel">
  …
</div>
<!-- enough other content to make the document scroll -->
```

and some CSS

```css
.navbar-fixed-top {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Then the following JS will give you the requested behavior.

```js
var docked = false;
var menu = document.getElementById('panel');
var init = menu.offsetTop;

function scrollTop() {
  return document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
}

window.onscroll = function () {
  if (!docked && (menu.offsetTop - scrollTop() < 0)) {
    menu.style.top = 0;
    menu.className = 'navbar-fixed-top';
    docked = true;
  } else if (docked && scrollTop() <= init) {
    menu.style.top = init + 'px';
    menu.className = menu.className.replace('navbar-fixed-top', '');
    docked = false;
  }
};
```

This example works in Firefox, Chrome, Opera and Safari. Internet Explorer needs a workaround.

Comment: I don't need to expand like the example I gave I just figured that out, I'm going to try your code and get back to you. Thnaks for posting.

Comment: Not working :( how weird, perhaps the css for #panel i posted is interfering in some way?

Comment: I’m not sure, if it is clear to you, that you must add a class `.navbar-fixed-top { position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; }` to your CSS.

Comment: What does “follow the scroller” mean? Which browser are you using? I just saw, that it doesn’t work in IE.

Comment: chrome/ff/opera latest version as I'm running linux mint.

Comment: That’s strange. Could you go to [lesscss.org](http://lesscss.org/) and see, if the menu bar ("overview", "usage" "language", "source", "about") is becoming sticky, when scrolling down?

Comment: it's going to try one more time placing the javascript on top of other scripts.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, try https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed.  Basic usage would be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#panel').scrollToFixed();
});
```

... however, see the link for options (e.g. allowing for footer panels when the user scrolls down, etc).